# Attached events: handling MenuItem.Click

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to understand Attached Events. Any idea why the Grid_Click_1 is not called when a MenuItem is clicked?

```
<Border MenuItem.Click="Grid_Click_1" Height="200" Background="Black">
    <Border.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Test" />
            <MenuItem Header="Test2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Border.ContextMenu>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContextMenu` is not part of the main Visual Tree therefore `Click` event will not bubble to `Border` element. `ContextMenu` has its own Visual Tree, which is created by the [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) control, and you can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx#PopupandtheVisualTree) or [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/RoutedCommandsInContextMenu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it does not work since the context menu isn't in the same visual tree